# php function inside another function?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I created a contact form on my classified ads website.
I use the following function to get the uploader email :

```
public function uploadermail()
{
    return $this->User_id?$this->User->email:lang('anonymous');
}
```

It works fine and I get the result using an echo :

```
<?php echo $image->uploadermail(); ?>
```

Then I use a function to send the mail :

```
public static function sendmail_anon()
{
    $form = new Form('sendmail_anon');

    $form->field('email', 'text', array
    (
        'valid_email'   =>  true
    ));

    $form->field('message', 'textarea', array
    (
        'min_length'    =>  25
    ));

    if($data = $form->validate())
    {
        $envoi = array
        (
            'message'   =>  $data['message'],
            'email' =>  $data['email']
        );

        mail($data['email'], lang('account_details'), lang('email_contact', $envoi), 'From: noreply@'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    }

    return $form;
}
```

The problem is that this is sending the mail to the e-mail from the form field.
I would like to replace $data['email'] and insert the uploadermail instead. I tried :

```
mail($image->uploadermail(), lang('account_det.....
```

And it returns the following error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function uploadermail() on a non-object
```

Is it possible to do and how should I writte it exactly ?

I tried :

```
 mail($uploadermail,....
```

And it doesn't returns errors, but didn't received any mail, how can I check what exactly contains $uploadermail on the browser ?

Comment: There's 2 mails : the one from the member that is actually connected, and the other one (uploadermail) from the member that posted the ad, and that is not connected and doesn't have any session.
And the mail that I need is the one that is static on the database. It should be simple but I'm confused with codeigniter :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that `$image` is not an class instance. So you cannot do `$image->uploadermail()`.

You can check it out by doing: `var_dump($image);`

After posting your full code I see you are accessing that function from `public static function sendmail_member()`:

```
mail($image?$image->uploadermail():$data['email'], lang('account_details'), lang('email_contact', $envoi), 'From: noreply@'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

However `$image` is never declared (/ instantiated) in that scope. Upon further investigation I see that there is a method called `uploadermail` in the correct class which I guess you are trying to access.

So to access that method you should do:

```
self::uploadermail()
```

or

```
$this->uploadermail()
```

**PS**

You should really try to prevent using `static`s. Static stuff are basically `global`s and they [tightly couple you code](http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/27/Dont-be-STUPID-GRASP-SOLID.html) and it prevent the `L` in [SOLID programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Comment: I did the var_dump and I got loads of data, including the uploadermail

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I'm a php beginner.
You can check the result of the var_dump here :
http://www.veloccasion.net/Fc/

Comment: I think I know what you mean. Actually, I myself pasted the method called uploadermail. I tried using self::uploadermail() and it returns : 

    `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`

Referring to this line : 

`return this->User_id?$this->User->email:lang('anonymous');`

Comment: Well anyway, I'm not good enough at this point to understand how is acting php. 
Are you available to hire ? In that case you could help with this problem and some other things I would like to add to the website.

Comment: @Jamescoo sorry I have way to much work to do right now for myself

Answer (score 0):

You should instantinate an object for $image before usage! e.g.

```
$image = new ... 
or
$image = x.GetImage(...
```

Comment: It's relly odd! it should trap an error OR send an email because $image is null or is not null; not both, not no one!